# Tools to export shps from Oracle database

Tags: qgis, shapefile, open-source-gis, export, oracle-spatial

What open source tools could be used to export shapefiles from an Oracle database. I have tried using QGIS but it does crash way too much.

Comment: How large are the source tables?  The .dbf and .shp file size limitations will limit *any* shapefile export at some point (and the restriction is to the first failure - .shp or .dbf).

Comment: Not sure about the size of the source table.But big enough to crash QGIS after connecting.

Comment: I should also ask if you're trying to export from Oracle **native** spatial, or back-end SDE tables?

Comment: From Oracle native spatial

Comment: You only get 2Gb (2^31-1) in either .dbf or .shp before the write is going to crash, so the sum of the widths of the fields and the number of average vertices are going to be your limiting factors (on a per row basis).  You'd have to edit the question to include a DESCRIBE on the table(s) with row count and feature vertex density before this can really be answered.

Comment: If Qgis is crashing soon after connecting it is probably some other issue than size of the table.

Answer (score 3):

You could use GDAL which supports Oracle Spatial: http://www.gdal.org/drv_oci.html